# Create Avro file directly to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, avro

I'd like to skip the step of creating an avro file locally and uploading it directly to Google Cloud Storage.

I checked the blob.upload from_string option but honestly I don't know what it should replace to apply to my code. And I don't know if it's the best way out for what I need. With that I could build a more modern pipeline by including the script inside a docker image.

This can be done somehow based on the script below:

```
import csv
import base64
import json
import io
import avro.schema
import avro.io
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
import math
import os
import gcloud
from gcloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

try:
    script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
except:
    script_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Keys\\key.json"

#Bigquery Credentials and settings
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = script_path

folder = str((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
bucket_name = 'gs://new_bucket/table/*.csv'
dataset = 'dataset'
tabela = 'table'

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("C:\\Users\\me\\schema_table.avsc", "rb").read())  

writer = DataFileWriter(open("C:\\Users\\me\\table_register.avro", "wb"), avro.io.DatumWriter(), schema)


def insert_bigquery(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('id','STRING',mode='REQUIRED')
    ]
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.field_delimiter = ";"
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')

#insert_bigquery(bucket_name, dataset, tabela)

def get_data_from_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    #Busca IDs
    query = """SELECT id FROM dataset.base64_data"""
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    return rows

a = get_data_from_bigquery()
length = len(a) 
line_count = 0

for row in range(length):
    bytes = base64.b64decode(str(a[row][0]))
    bytes = bytes[5:]
    buf = io.BytesIO(bytes)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(buf)
    rec_reader = avro.io.DatumReader(avro.schema.Parse(open("C:\\Users\\me\\schema_table.avsc").read()))
    out=rec_reader.read(decoder)
    writer.append(out)
writer.close()

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob("insert_transfer/" + destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name
    ))

upload_blob('new_bucket', 'C:\\Users\\me\\table_register.avro', 'table_register.avro')
```

Comment: What size are the files? If they are not large, meaning smaller than available free memory, build the avro files in memory and upload blob from string. Otherwise, you will have to stream data into Cloud Storage which is not easy meaning no Google libraries to use.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you show me a example based in this script? My files aren´t large!

Comment: Sorry, I do not own the code that I wrote for Avro. My comment is to give you an idea of a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your script and I can see that you are getting data from BigQuery. I can confirm you that I reproduced your scenario and I am able to export data from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage directly, without creating the avro file locally.

I suggest you to take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) where it describes how to export table data from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Open the BigQuery web UI in your Cloud Console.
2. In the navigation panel, in the Resources section, expand your project and click 
   your dataset to expand it. Find and click the table that contains the data you're 
   exporting.
3. On the right side of the window, click Export then select Export to Cloud Storage
4. In the Export to Cloud Storage dialog:

   - For Select Cloud Storage location, browse for the bucket.
   - For Export format, choose the format for your exported data, in your specific 
     case, choose “Avro”.
   - Click Export.

Nonetheless, there’s also the possibility to do it with Python. I recommend you to take a look [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/371c4f270b9a8c3e1c3b87e6edfdda1a61ae5e89/bigquery/docs/snippets.py).

I hope this approach works for you.

Comment: I need to make a BigQuery data transformation before converting to avro. In that case, the solution does not suit me!

Comment: Since you are trying to do some kind of transformation after retrieving it from BigQuery, my best solution would be to download the file once is converted into Avro, and then do the upload to your Google Cloud Storage Bucket.  

Finally, once is uploaded to your Cloud Storage Bucket, you can delete it.